# Using a custom Combiner...it may be ignored?

Tags: hadoop

I have this in Main...

```
    job.setMapperClass(AverageIntMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(AverageIntCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(AverageIntReducer.class);
```

And the Combiner has different code but the Combiner is being completely ignored as the output the Reducer is using is the output from the Mapper.

I understand that a Combiner may not be used but I thought that was the case when the Combiner is the same as the Reducer.  I don't really understand the point of being able to create a custom Combiner but the system can still skip its usage.

If that's not supposed to happen, what could be a reason that the Combiner is not being used?

Code...

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class AverageInt {

public static class AverageIntMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String n_string = value.toString();
        context.write(new Text("Value"), new Text(n_string));
    }
}

public static class AverageIntCombiner extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for(IntWritable value : values) {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
            sum += value.get();
            count += 1;
        }

        String sum_count = Integer.toString(sum) + "," + Integer.toString(count);

        context.write(key, new Text(sum_count));
    }
}

public static class AverageIntReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for(Text value : values) {
            String temp = value.toString();
            String[] split = temp.split(",");
            total += Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            count += Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        }

        Double average = (double)total/count;

        context.write(key, new Text(average.toString()));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: AverageInt <input path> <output path>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(AverageInt.class);
    job.setJobName("Average");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(AverageIntMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(AverageIntCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(AverageIntReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

Comment: How do you know its being ignored? Are there no counts for the combiner?

Comment: @BinaryNerd The value that gets created in the Combiner has a delimiter that I try to then split on in the Reducer but I get array out of bounds errors when I try to split.  if I remove the logic to split in the Reducer and just output the values it's getting as input, it's what the Mapper is outputting.

Comment: I would post your code, otherwise its unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @BinaryNerd ok I've added my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what your mapper is emitting:

`public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)`

Its sending two `Text` objects, but whilst you've declared the combiner class itself correctly, the reduce method has:

`public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

It should be:

`public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)`

Comment: That looks like it fixed the issue.  I guess I didn't notice the issue since there weren't any errors when compiling / executing.

Comment: Its an easy mistake to make, hadoop will have been using the base implementation in the Reduce class which just passes the data through without modifying it.